# Error en thymeleaf - Failed to refresh data from process

Tags: html5, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Mi proyecto Spring Boot tiene problemas al intentar cargar el contenido de los documentos HTML. Sólo carga el texto plano.

Este es el error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es muy sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se visualiza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a realizar

> Mave->Update proyect

pero no funciona

Este es mi pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Empleos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Empleos</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí la solución. Era mas simple de lo que parecía y no tiene nada que ver con la configuración del pom.xml, maven, etc.

El código correcto en este caso sería:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{

@GetMapping("/")
  public String inicio(Model model){
  model.addAtributte("message","New message send by parameter");
  return "index"
}
```

El trabajo de @Controller es crear un Mapa del objeto modelo y encontrar una vista, pero @RestController simplemente devuelve el objeto y los datos del objeto se escriben directamente en la respuesta HTTP como JSON o XML.

En el siguiente enlace lo explica muy bien
Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/08/difference-between-restcontroller-and-controller-annotations-spring-mvc-rest.html#ixzz6GETPXQPS